# C++ Overflow when counting the number of K Inverse Pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, integer-overflow

Given two integers n and k, I want to calculate how many different arrays consist of numbers from 1 to n such that there are exactly k inverse pairs. (i.e. pairs i,j such that `i<j` and `a[i]>a[j]`) Mod 10^9+7.

I am using dynamic programming, I defined `DP[i][j]` as the number of arrays with i elements with exactly j inversions, then I derived the recurrence:

`DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j]+dp[i-1][j-1]+...+dp[i-1][j-i+1]`

In addition, I noticed that:

`DP[i][j-1]=DP[i-1][j-1]+DP[i-1][j-2]+...+DP[i-1][j-i]`

Hence, combining both sums, we get:

`DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j]+DP[i][j-1]-DP[i-1][j-i]`

I wrote the following dynamic programming solution which is working for large n untill n,k around 800. However, once I pass these values (for example, n=1000, k=990), the result overflows and I am not sure why that happens. Here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    long long MOD = 1e9+7;
    int kInversePairs(int n, int k) {
        vector< vector<long long> > dp(1001, vector<long long>(1001, -1));
        return solve(dp, n, k);
    }
    long long solve(vector< vector<long long> >& dp, int n, int k){
        if (k<0)return 0;
        if (k==0)return 1;
        if (n==0)return 0;
        if (dp[n][k]!=-1)return dp[n][k];
        dp[n][k]=solve(dp, n-1, k)%MOD;
        dp[n][k]+=solve(dp, n, k-1)%MOD;
        dp[n][k]-=solve(dp, n-1, k-n)%MOD;
        //if (dp[n][k]<0){
        //    cout << "Overflow: " << solve(dp, n-1, k-n) << " " << solve(dp, n-1, k) <<  " " << solve(dp, n, k-1) << endl;
        //}
        return dp[n][k]%=MOD;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can the person who down voted explain why he down voted? I have clearly tried a lot, my question is clear, and I am not asking anyone to solve my homework (which this isn't). It seems that any questions that I post these days on stack overflow get down voted for absolutely no reason!

Comment: `int kInversePairs`,  `long long solve` -- see an issue with this?  Your compiler should have warned you when you return the result of `solve` from `kInversePairs`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, changing it to long long still overflows. All the answers are taken mod 1e9+7 which is represent able on an int so that's still not the problem, but even if it was then changing int to long long does no change the overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer eventually. I am adding it here for completion.

After the line `dp[n][k]-=solve(dp, n-1, k-n)%MOD;`, there was a possibility that dp[n][k] is less than zero because we were taking modulo MOD at every moment, so even if the actual value of dp[n][k] before this line was 1e20, we are taking modulo MOD so its value might drop to even zero. So after this line, the value might be negative.

The way I solved this is by adding +MOD before taking the last modulo. Here is working code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    long long MOD = 1e9+7;
    int kInversePairs(int n, int k) {
        vector< vector<long long> > dp(1001, vector<long long>(1001, -1));
        return solve(dp, n, k);
    }
    long long solve(vector< vector<long long> >& dp, int n, int k){
        if (k<0)return 0;
        if (k==0)return 1;
        if (n==0)return 0;
        if (dp[n][k]!=-1)return dp[n][k];
        dp[n][k]=solve(dp, n-1, k)%MOD;
        dp[n][k]+=solve(dp, n, k-1)%MOD;
        dp[n][k]-=solve(dp, n-1, k-n)%MOD;
        dp[n][k]+=MOD; //just in case it became negative 
        return dp[n][k]%=MOD;
    }
};
```

Comment: That makes sense. The [adaptation I've used for this](http://ideone.com/xOtZtH), born from the *outstanding* k-inverse-pairs article on leet-code, adds the modulo factor in as part of the first step. I had just noticed yours was missing that when you posted this answer, so +1, sir. glad you fixed it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Funnily enough, I skimmed over their solution several time and was scratching my head because I thought my solution was exactly the one shown. After finally figuring out my mistake, I went back to the article and I found that this was indeed the only difference between my solution and theirs :)